# Including customer details in Stripe emails

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, stripe

I have one of those questions that I have no idea how to phrase…

Basically Stripe is sending an email notification to my client's ‘accounts department’ on successful payment, but it only includes their email address and the value of their order.

What they’ve requested is that it also includes the customer name in the email that goes to the accounts department.

From looking at the details of a Stripe Event I can see that none of the address details are in there, so either we’ve messed up with out integration, or commerce doesn’t send this info?

Is anyone able to shed some light on that?

Answer (score 3):

Probably best to use Craft Commerce emails, then you can put whatever information you want into the emails to your accounts departments. Like: `{{ order.billingAddress.fullName }}`

If the billing address information is not being sent to Stripe, you might need to modify your checkout.js or stripe.js payment screen implementation to ensure it sends the billing address information through along with the card info: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#stripe-create-token

Unlike other gateways, Stripe is building the card request within javascript to make the token, when our server sends the payment request, it only uses that token - no billing address is sent again.